# Creating Automated Date Capture and Age Calculation for List Items

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have been developing lists for SharePoint and am always adding new features.
The last feature I added involved a custom "Kanban" view which uses a WebPart embedded in tables which holds custom view for each items status (NEW, IN PROGRESS, COMPLETED)

Here is my issue, I needed a Field that would track the amount of time that has passed since the status of a list item has been moved to IN-PROGRESS from NEW and return that value in days (Minus weekends)

So far, I have a rudimentary solution for this issue where I have DEVS enter in the date they started working on a ticket, compare that date to today, then calculate it as:

```
=IF([CR Status]="IN PROGRESS",[Age in Days]-([Age in Days]/7)*2,"")
```

What I want to do is remove the manual date entry by my team and have SharePoint-Designer fill that role and have a permanent literal string that serves as a **StartDate** for the calculation.

Keep in mind these tickets have NO expiration or due date, the current date is also set automatically via. Designer-Workflow every 6 hours.

For reference, this is the calculation that gives me the raw amount of days between the Manually set start date and the current date.

```
Age in Days =IF([CR Status]="IN PROGRESS",Today-[In Progress Start Date],"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SPD workflow that runs on modified, checks if [CR Status] is "IN PROGRESS" and if [In Progress Start Date] is empty then set set [In Progress Start Date] it to Today.

Comment: I tried setting the SPD auto update, however I was having issues getting the field to accept a null value for the check.
Do you know of any workarounds to set the null value?

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQoRk.png

Comment: You can check against 1/1/1900 I believe.

Comment: That won't work, I have a feeling that it will automatically replace the current values/dates I have already set for the In Progress.
I need to get a null value for items that haven't already been  added

Comment: Have confirmed on a test site that this will reset the value that already exists